# merge the code of groupby ffill then bfill

Tags: pandas

In the following code, I want to do `ffill` then `bfill` according to `item_name`,code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"date":['1/1/2021','1/2/2021','1/3/2021','1/4/2021','1/5/2021','1/1/2021','1/2/2021','1/3/2021','1/4/2021','1/5/2021'],
                 "item_name":["bracelet","bracelet","bracelet","bracelet","bracelet","earring","earring","earring","earring","earring"],
                 "quantity_sold":[np.nan,np.nan,3,4,np.nan,100,200,300,400,500]})
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
display(df)
#sort on the right fields before the calculation
df=df.sort_values(['item_name','date'])
#sum of quantity for last 3 days (curr_day-2,curr_day-1,curr_day)
df['quantity_sold']=df.groupby("item_name")['quantity_sold'].ffill()
df['quantity_sold']=df.groupby("item_name")['quantity_sold'].bfill()
df
```

original table:
[image]

table after ffill then bfill:
[image]

The question is, is there a way to group following code from two lines into one?

```
df['quantity_sold']=df.groupby("item_name")['quantity_sold'].ffill()
df['quantity_sold']=df.groupby("item_name")['quantity_sold'].bfill()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing this in 2 seperate lines:-

```
df['quantity_sold']=df.groupby("item_name")['quantity_sold'].ffill()
df['quantity_sold']=df.groupby("item_name")['quantity_sold'].bfill()
```

Write this in a single line by method chaining it:-

```
df['quantity_sold']=df.groupby("item_name")['quantity_sold'].ffill().bfill()
```

Comment: How do you make sure the bfill does not fill for other `item_name` by coincidence

Comment: because you firstly using `ffill()` method after that `bfill()` method